# Big O notation for an if else selection statement with for loops

Tags: c, algorithm, performance, big-o

```
if (A[1][1] == 0)
  for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    for (j=0; j<n; j++)
      A[i][j] = 0;
else
  for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    A[i][i] = 1;
```

I'm looking for the big O notation for this code.
I've tried to understand the program but I just couldn't get the hold of it.

Comment: best case O(N) worst case O(N^2)?

Comment: WTB some indentation. You working on a decwriter from the 70's or something?

Comment: The complexity of an `if` statement is the worst complexity of either alternative.

Comment: I've figured out the same thing it should be O(n^2) right for the worst case??

Answer (score 3):

The time required to complete the following is proportional to `n`, so the following is O(n):

```
for (i=0; i<n; i++)
  A[i][i] = 1;
```

The time required to complete the following is proportional to `n*n` which is n<sup>2</sup>, so the following is O(n<sup>2</sup>):

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
  for (j=0; j<n; j++)
    A[i][j] = 0;
```

The snippet will execute one of these, but not both. As such, the worse case is bound by the worse of those two options, so it's O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Answer (score 0):

Big O notation simply means nearest upper bound. It is completely unrelated to worst or best or average case.
It is safe to say that O(n²) satisfies both the condition.

Comment: Re "*It is completely unrelated to worst or best or average case*", It's usually used to describe the upper bound of the worst case, but it can also be used to describe the upper bound of the best case and the upper bound of the average too.